# How can I add TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.1 to ssl protocols?

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl

Even if I don't add TLSv1.3, still only TLSv1.3 appears.

How can I add TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.1 to ssl protocols?

You can check on this link: https://ibb.co/4WYd0Jw

[image]

it is my nginx conf:

```
ssl_session_cache shared:le_nginx_SSL:1m;
ssl_session_timeout 1440m;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

It is my nginx and openssl version:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.18.0
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
TLS SNI support enabled
```

Comment: For a website, you should focus on just TLS 1.2 (or more) except if you have very real specific reasons of needing lower versions. Most browsers will drop support for TLS 1.0 or 1.1 soon anyway.

Comment: Are you sure the tool you use show all possible cases and not just what it was able to negotiate which is normally the highest possible version, which is fine. Try with `testssl.sh` or Qualys SSLlabs. However your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: Also, just TLS 1.2 is ok. But I couldn't add it. Sorry, I am new on server configuration. that's why I don't understand so much. Now there is only TLS 1.3 and flutter doesn't support. So I need to add TLS 1.2